# select clipart from library and add to DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to know how i can create an image library inside a website and let the user pick an image from the library and add it inside a div. for example i have a white shirt as a background and in my image library i have multiple images that the user can use for his shirt design. where would i go to find information on how to do it? i have been looking everywhere but cant seem to find an answer i don't even know what it would be called. im using jquery UI in my rest of the code that i have done if that makes a difference.
something like this https://www.customink.com/lab

go to add art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an img tag inside your div with some sort of id.  Add an onclick function to your images

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iXHPRVf.jpg" alt="Dog" width="300" height="300" onclick="clickedPhoto(this.src)">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/BHoIzPj.jpg" alt="Cat" width="300" height="300" onclick="clickedPhoto(this.src)">
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
</div>

<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
  
  function clickedPhoto(src) {
    modalImg.src = src;
  }
</script>
```